# Query WCF Web Service from SSRS report

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, reporting-services, datasource

I have simple wcf web service that returns xml when called.
It returns something like:

```
<PCR>
<title>Project Control Report</title>
<pages>290</pages>
</PCR>
```

The web service is currently deployed on my test machine and can be invoked through browser with :

http://localhost:62722/PCRWebService.svc/getReportData

In SSRS, for Data Source type I picked XML and I am now trying to specify Query in Data Set properties to call my web service. So far, after trying at least 20 examples I could find online, I couldn't make it work. Error is always the same: **Invalid URI: URI is empty.**

Here is one of my tries:

```
<Query>
<Method Namespace="http://localhost:62722/PCRWebService.svc/getListPlayers" Name="getListPlayers"></Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Here is one of the examples I tried:
http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/webservice-as-datasource-in-ssrs/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/wcf-service-as-datasource-in-ssrs/) post from the same blog. I have followed every step and my report displays the items correctly.

Comment: @bobetko If you can't get it to work I can upload my solutions somewhere for you to download.